# Can I use the same SIP library as Skype

Tags: sip

I'm looking to rebuild an existing VOIP app for android and iphone because it has poor call quality.  I would like to replace my SIP library with the same one that Skype uses.

Does anyone know which SIP library Skype uses?  Is it an open source one?  Is it something proprietary that they built?  Is it commercially available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skype has a proprietary signalling protocol and the code is not available. A [lot of articles](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=skype%20signalling%20protocol&btnG=&hl=pt-PT&as_sdt=0,5) have been written about the subject. Here you have an [example](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~library/TR-repository/reports/reports-2004/cucs-039-04.pdf).

Skype performs the signalling over several ports and protocols and it can even send it encapsulated inside HTTP protocol so that it can still work on limited networks. I don't know what made you say that Skype uses SIP, but I don't think that it is used. I believe it is a small proprietary protocol and you can find some evidences for this in several articles where packets were analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

Skype doesn't use SIP.   Skype had other issues to deal with that SIP doesn't handle well.  For example, SIP doesn't like NAT very much and several hacks must be used to get around it as best as one can.  Skype, at least before the Microsoft era, used a proprietary protocol peer-to-peer (remember what Skype USED to make :-) ), and had the concept of Supernodes.   Supernodes were other Skype nodes that had public IP addresses.   Skype nodes would attempt to do a peer-to-peer call, but, in the event things like NAT and firewalls got in the way, they could relay their conversations from a Supernode.   Again. who knows what they do now that Microsoft has been in the code.   We know that Microsoft does inspect their messages.

What is the issue with SIP?   If it's that NAT traversal issue - there are variants of protocols such as IAX where all traffic goes over a single stream, avoiding the SIP media problem.